# JSF 1.2 inputText truncates text on quotation marks

Tags: jsf-1.2, quotation-marks

JSF 1.2 inputText normally is able to show value with quotation marks. In the current system these are treated as part of HTML and therefore the source code gets truncated.

Do you have any hints what could cause this issue?
Thanks!

The input text is: Test with "quotation marks"

[image: Quotation marks interpreted in HTML]

[image: Truncated inputText]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has emerged that this was a bug in the JSF library. I had to switch to another version.